# Insufficient permissions when link Google AdWords account and Google Analytics via API

Tags: google-analytics, integration, google-ads-api

I want to link Google AdWords account to Google Analytics one via API.

I have

- Google AdWords Manager Account (with created some sub accounts)
- Google Analytics Account with (with created account, property and some views)

To achive this i'm using this method https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webPropertyAdWordsLinks/insert

When i use "API Explorer" or doing it manually (via web interface) everything works fine, but when I'm trying example code from documentation all I receive is this error:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this web property."}],"code":403,"message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this web property."}}
```

I'm using Google PHP Client Library. Google Analytics Account was created **with the same email** as for AdWords Manager Account.

What's up with these permission? Do i need more configuration?

UPDATE

For GA authentication i follow up these tutorial: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php
So after visit: https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=analytics&credential=client_key
i have ended up with json file:

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "....",
    "private_key_id": "...",
    "private_key": "..."
    "client_email": "...@metal-hologram-.....iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "...",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/..."
}
```

client_email i've added in GA -> Admin -> User management -> add account (with full permissions)

AdWords authentication done here:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ -> credential -> OAuth - > Application type: Other -> OAuth

Refresh token generated by script: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/Auth/GetRefreshToken.php

Comment: Are you using service accounts to issue the API queries? Can you share more information on how you are doing authentication on the API?

Comment: @Eduardo i've updated my post.

Comment: Did you also add that service account with full access to your AdWords?

Comment: You mean: AdWords -> Settings -> Setup -> Account Access -> Add -> "...@metal-hologram-.....iam.gserviceaccount.com" ?

Comment: Yes. Thebuser that issues the linking command. In this case the service account. Need edit access to both GA and AdWords.

Comment: But "...@metal-hologram-.....iam.gserviceaccount.com" i not really email. Invitation will not come.